# Geoserver WFS-T insert exception

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, gml, wfs-t, ows

I'm creating a new WFS-T feature but I'm getting the below exception when I try to send the feature:

> No such feature type http://IP:PORT/geoserver/CARBONITA:bairros

**link to gist:**
 https://gist.github.com/oiacrasec/e82a0fe6e30cfd5f8770fbfd43b6a49e

gist contains:
 - Geoserver capabilities
 - XML sent
 - XML received
 - Project files

Answer (score 2):

your featureNS should be http://localhost:8080/CARBONITA instead

Comment: Hello, i changed from:

var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/CARBONITA',
    featureType: 'bairros',
    srsName: epsg
});

to:

var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'http://localhost:8080/CARBONITA',
    featureType: 'bairros',
    srsName: epsg
});

Got the exception:
No such feature type http://localhost:8080/CARBONITA:bairros

Comment: PS: My geoserver is online, im not running in localhost. Im using localhost here just for example.

Comment: I dont know if this helps, when i edit my workspace the URI is http://localhost:8080/CARBONITA

if i change to the real IP the sourceWFS doesnt work. I had to set localhost in workspace URI and i had to set in javascript the real IP.

Comment: Another important thing, everything i have was imported from a shapefile.

Comment: You mention that the server is online. Is it possible to access the server in order to check why the calls are failing?